When is the preposition "de" used with the conditional form of deber?
According to this site

Deber + infinitivo expresa obligación o suposición y deber de +
infinitivo solo indica suposición


Sin embargo, en los medios de comunicación es muy habitual encontrar frases en las que se emplea inapropiadamente deber de + infinitivo cuando lo que se pretende expresar es obligación

Used this way to my understanding means "must" indicating obligation or suppositon.
However, asking my language learning partner for examples resulted in some examples using the conditional form of deber:


Si se te acabaron los frijoles, deberías de ir al mercado a comprar más
Deberías de dormir al menos 8 horas
Deberías de descansar aunque sea los domingos


From my understanding it means should used more for giving advice.
Adding to the confusion, I was told that these example sentences can all be rewritten without the preposition de.
Technically speaking,

You can use should for suppositions


They should be at the mall by now.


You can use should for obligations


I can't think of a good example but I can imagine a mother saying to
her child "You should eat your food" and meaning it in an obligatory
way.


you can use should to mean advice


You should go to the mall from time to time.

I suppose when i think of it as "should" vs "must" they seem like different concepts, but thinking of them as "suppositions vs obligations" makes it clearer. However, the problem is the idea of "making suggestions" with the conditional form of deber that no longer makes it clear as a native english speaker.
Following The the logic given, we have
supposition

Ellos deberían estar en el centro comercial por ahora
Ellos deberían de estar en el centro comercial por ahora

obligation (i'm not sure about this one because it even sounds weird trying to think of it as an obligation)

Deberias ir al centro comercial
Deberias de ir al centro comercial (not correct but is also used)

Giving advice (now we come to the gray area)

Deberías dormir al menos 8 horas
Deberías de dormir al menos 8 horas

What's going on here? How do we decide when to use "de* in these cases?

You should only use de in the first case, when you are expressing a supposition:

Ellos deberían de estar en el centro comercial ahora.

(Notice that I used ahora instead of por ahora; at least in Spain, por ahora means up to now, not about this time).
In this case, what you say is: based on what I know, I guess they are at the mall at this time. It may be that I know their habits, or their plans for today, or whatever. And you can use the indicative instead of the subjunctive to express that you are fairly sure of what you say:

Ellos deben de estar en el centro comercial ahora.

For anything else, you should not use de. You can consider that giving advice is just a mild form of giving an order, so the correct use is just the same; the only difference is that you use the subjunctive, instead of the indicative, to soften the expression. More or less, the translation into English would be:

Debes ir al centro comercial. -> You must go to the mall.


Deberías ir al centro comercial. -> You should go to the mall.

Your last case is just a variation on this. It does not express a supposition, so you do not use de:

Deberías dormir al menos ocho horas. -> You should sleep at least eight hours.


Just to confirm, are you saying I should not use "Deber + infinitive" to express supposition but only for obligations. Also since advice is seen as a milder form of a command it follows the "Deber + infinitive" construction.

@PersonalInformation Until a few years ago, I would have said that. Nowadays you can use deber + infinitive in all cases, though deber de + infinitive is clearer for suppositions.


Deber + infinitive (expresses an obligation: must or be obliged to):
o   Debo estudiar para el examen. (I must study for the exam.)
Tener que + infinitive (have to):
o   Tengo que ir al trabajo temprano. (I have to go to work early.)
Deber (used as should, expresses an obligation that is more subjective, gives advice or presents an opinion):
o   Deberías comer más verduras. (You should eat more vegetables.)
Tener que (expresses an obligation based on objective criteria):
o   Tienes que tomar esta medicina cada ocho horas. (You have to take this medicine every eight hours.)
Deber de + infinitive (expresses probability, uncertainty, and supposition: must be or must have):
o   Debe de estar lloviendo; el suelo está mojado. (It must be raining; the ground is wet.)

